# Horizontal lines on screen on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, display

I have a Dell laptop with i5 and a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 to which I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome).  Whenever anything major on the screen changes like loading a web page or opening the activities page the screen updates by line horizontally (like a TV does if you have seen one in slow-motion). I've tried installing nvidia drivers nvidia-384 and 390 individually, from

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

with `sudo apt install nvidia-` they only boot to black screen so I removed them - I could however access tty.   This problem also occurred with 18.04.  When I tried the two versions of Ubuntu by live-USB the problem did not exist.

How should I resolve this issue?
System details:
[image: Neofetch data]

---

EDIT: I've tried installing nvidia-384 and 390 through the terminal. The problem was in 18.04 too. This did not happen in the USB live session

I've recorded a video of the problem [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/268453833208889345/440204476138127361/video.mov) so you can better understand what's going on.